# Dilution of Concentrated TiCl4 using deionized water

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, experimental-chemistry

How can we dilute conc TiCl4 (>99%) to 20 % w/w, using only DI water?

Answer (score 1):

Since $\ce{TiCl4}$ hydrolyzes rapidly in air, releasing $\ce{HCl}$, you need a *good* hood and protective equipment.

Put the *chilled* $\ce{TiCl4}$ into a separatory (dropping) funnel or burette with stopcock that can be adjusted to let one drop at a time flow into *chilled* water. Since the m.p. of $\ce{TiCl4}$ is −24 °C, you can use an ice-water bath to keep things cool.

There is a good [demonstration video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CX7fkf21trs) available.